# Javascript visiblity toggle with onscroll

Tags: javascript, visibility

```
var headPos = window.scrollY;
window.onscroll = function(){
    headPos = window.scrollY;
}

window.onscroll = visi;

function visi(){
    if(headPos < 1300){
        document.getElementById("goBackUp").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else if(headPos > 1301){
        document.getElementById("goBackUp").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

Hello,  so I wanted to have the ability to show this scrollToTop button on my html page using scroll position but it  doesn't seem to work correctly.

Comment: your problem is with reassigning window.onscroll. You should make one function to encapsulate everything

Comment: Great this this is working for you. To close this up, you can either delete this question (recommended), or you could rephrase the title and add your own answer for the case where someone else may be having this same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So several things, specifically your doubled `onscroll`. See simplified example below.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("goBackUp");

handleScroll = () => btn.style.display = (window.scrollY < 1300) ? 'none' : 'block';

document.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
```

```css
#goBackUp {
  position: fixed;
  right: 1rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: #0f0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="goBackUp">GO BACK UP</div>

<br><br><br>
Now Scroll down....
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: I do like your funny words, funny man. Thank you.  Especially for the third line, it looks very clean.

Answer (score 0):

I think you owerwrote the assigned function to window onscroll every time you assigned a new function.

Use one function instead, like this:

If you comment out the console log, you can see the scrollY value, on every scroll event.

```js
window.onscroll = visi;

function visi(){
 headPos = window.scrollY;
 //console.log(headPos);
    if(headPos < 1300){
        document.getElementById("goBackUp").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else if(headPos > 1300){
        document.getElementById("goBackUp").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:black;height:1800px"></div>
<div id="goBackUp">Go back up</div>
```